# Why does Apache2 disable DISPLAY environment variable?

Tags: apache2, environment-variables

Is there any configuration file to modify in order to enable the DISPLAY environment variable before apache2 makes the call to my cgi-script?

Comment: If you're trying to run some CGI script that needs `DISPLAY` environment variable, you are probably looking for `xvfb-run` instead of trying to set the environment variable matching the actual display connected to the server.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does Apache2 disable DISPLAY environment variable?

Apache does not disable it since Apache does not know a DISPLAY variable. DISPLAY is related to the X Window system.

If you want to set DISPLAY I would use `/etc/rc.local`. But you must make sure that the command for setting the DISPLAY variable is called before starting the application server.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
```